# Is there an easy way to request a URL in python and NOT follow redirects?

Tags: python, http, redirect

Looking at the source of urllib2 it looks like the easiest way to do it would be to subclass HTTPRedirectHandler and then use build_opener to override the default HTTPRedirectHandler, but this seems like a lot of (relatively complicated) work to do what seems like it should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Here is the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) way:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://github.com', allow_redirects=False)
print(r.status_code, r.headers['Location'])
```

Comment: Then look at `r.headers['Location']` to see where it would have sent you

Comment: Note that it seems that Requests will normalize `Location` to `location`.

Comment: @Hamish `requests` allows you to access headers both in the canonical form and in lowercase. See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-headers

Comment: As of 2019 in Python 3, this no longer appears to work for me.  (I get a key dict error.)

Comment: Check r.status_code if it is not 301 there might have been another error. The Location header is only available for redirects. Use dict.get if you want to avoid KeyError on optional keys.

Comment: TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_redirects'

Comment: Thanks, it's useful for my scenario. In this case I will be able to set the cookie for the domain to be redirected.

Answer (score 36):

[Dive Into Python](https://linux.die.net/diveintopython/html/http_web_services/redirects.html) has a good chapter on handling redirects with urllib2. Another solution is [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html).

```py
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.bogosoft.com")
>>> conn.request("GET", "")
>>> r1 = conn.getresponse()
>>> print r1.status, r1.reason
301 Moved Permanently
>>> print r1.getheader('Location')
http://www.bogosoft.com/new/location
```

Comment: Everybody who comes here from google, please note that the up to date way to go is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14678220/362951 The requests library will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: The link to "Dive Into Python" is dead.

Answer (score 12):

This is a urllib2 handler that will not follow redirects:

```
class NoRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        infourl = urllib.addinfourl(fp, headers, req.get_full_url())
        infourl.status = code
        infourl.code = code
        return infourl
    http_error_300 = http_error_302
    http_error_301 = http_error_302
    http_error_303 = http_error_302
    http_error_307 = http_error_302

opener = urllib2.build_opener(NoRedirectHandler())
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

Comment: I'm unit testing an API and dealing with a login method that redirects to a page I don't care about, but doesn't send the desired session cookie with the response to the redirect. This is exactly what I needed for that.

Answer (score 9):

The `redirections` keyword in the `httplib2` request method is a red herring. Rather than return the first request it will raise a `RedirectLimit` exception if it receives a redirection status code. To return the inital response you need to set `follow_redirects` to `False` on the `Http` object:

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http()
h.follow_redirects = False
(response, body) = h.request("http://example.com")
```

Answer (score 8):

i suppose this would help

```
from httplib2 import Http
def get_html(uri,num_redirections=0): # put it as 0 for not to follow redirects
conn = Http()
return conn.request(uri,redirections=num_redirections)
```

Answer (score 6):

The shortest way however is

```
class NoRedirect(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def redirect_request(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs, newurl):
        pass

noredir_opener = urllib2.build_opener(NoRedirect())
```

Comment: How is this the shortest way? It doesn't even contain the import or the actual request.

Comment: I already was going to post this solution and was quite surprised to find this answer at the bottom. It is very concise and should be the top answer in my opinion.

Comment: Moreover, it gives you more freedom, this way it's possible to [control which URLs to follow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28057731/3075942).

Comment: I confirm, this is the easist way. A short remark for those who want to debug. Do not forget that you may set multiples handlers when bullding the opener like : `opener = urllib.request.build_opener(debugHandler, NoRedirect())` where `debugHandler=urllib.request.HTTPHandler()` and `debugHandler.set_http_debuglevel (1)`. In the end: `urllib.request.install_opener(opener)`

Answer (score 5):

I second olt's pointer to [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.org/http_web_services/redirects.html). Here's an implementation using urllib2 redirect handlers, more work than it should be? Maybe, shrug.

```
import sys
import urllib2

class RedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_301(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):  
        result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_301( 
            self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)              
        result.status = code                                 
        raise Exception("Permanent Redirect: %s" % 301)

    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_302(
            self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)              
        result.status = code                                
        raise Exception("Temporary Redirect: %s" % 302)

def main(script_name, url):
   opener = urllib2.build_opener(RedirectHandler)
   urllib2.install_opener(opener)
   print urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv)
```

Comment: Looks wrong... This code does actually follow the redirects (by calling the original handler, thus issuing an HTTP request), and then raise an exception