# python get headers only using urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I have to implement a function to get headers only (without doing a GET or POST) using urllib2. Here is my function:

```
def getheadersonly(url, redirections = True):
    if not redirections:
        class MyHTTPRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
            def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
                return urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
            http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302
        cookieprocessor = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(MyHTTPRedirectHandler, cookieprocessor)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    class HeadRequest(urllib2.Request):
        def get_method(self):
            return "HEAD"

    info = {}
    info['headers'] = dict(urllib2.urlopen(HeadRequest(url)).info()) 
    info['finalurl'] = urllib2.urlopen(HeadRequest(url)).geturl() 
    return info
```

Uses code from answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2070916/842837) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/554580/842837). However this **is doing** redirection even when the flag is `False`. I tried the code with:

```
print getheadersonly("http://ms.com", redirections = False)['finalurl']
print getheadersonly("http://ms.com")['finalurl']
```

Its giving morganstanley.com in both cases. What is wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent Python's urllib(2) from following a redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554446/how-do-i-prevent-pythons-urllib2-from-following-a-redirect)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, your code contains several bugs:

1. On each request of `getheadersonly` you install a new global urlopener which is then used in subsequent calls of `urllib2.urlopen`
2. You make two HTTP-requests to get two different attributes of a response.
3. The implementation of `urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_302` is not so trivial and I do not understand how can it prevent redirections in the first place.

Basically, you should understand that each handler is installed in an opener to handle certain kind of response. `urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler` is there to convert certain http-codes into a redirections. If you do not want redirections, do not add a redirection handler into the opener. If you do not want to open ftp links, do not add `FTPHandler`, etc.

That is all you need is to create a new opener and add the `urllib2.HTTPHandler()` in it, customize the request to be 'HEAD' request and pass an instance of the request to the opener, read the attributes, and close the response.

```
class HeadRequest(urllib2.Request):
    def get_method(self):
        return 'HEAD'

def getheadersonly(url, redirections=True):
    opener = urllib2.OpenerDirector()
    opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPHandler())
    opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPDefaultErrorHandler())
    if redirections:
        # HTTPErrorProcessor makes HTTPRedirectHandler work
        opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPErrorProcessor())
        opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler())
    try:
        res = opener.open(HeadRequest(url))
    except urllib2.HTTPError, res:
        pass
    res.close()
    return dict(code=res.code, headers=res.info(), finalurl=res.geturl())
```

Comment: @jerrymouse, I slightly updated the code to correctly handle 40x and 50x errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can send a [HEAD request using httplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python). A [HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) request is the same as a GET request, but the server doesn't send then message body.

Comment: I am already doing that, check the 5th line from end. However the problem is that about redirection. Sometimes I dont want to follow redirection, whereas its always redirecting.