# requests: Retrieve final URL redirection without GET

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Per documentation of `requests.get` we have:

- https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

> By default Requests will perform location redirection for all verbs
> except HEAD.

So how would one write the following function without the actual GET operation (I discard the content anyway):

```
def get_location(url):
  response = requests.get(url) # HTML content is discarded
  return response.url
```

I did verify using `curl -I` a HEAD operation seems to contains the new location:

```
$ curl -I 'https://www.example.org/redirect.php?val=1'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Location: https://www.acme.corp/foobar.html
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after posting my question, I stumble upon:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9967683/136285

So this worked for me:

```
def get_location(url):
  response = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
  return response.url
```