# HTML: Get direct link to file from embed src

Tags: python, html, embed

I want to know how to get the direct link to an embedded video (the link to the .flv/.mp4 or whatever file) from just the embed link.

For example, http://www.kumby.com/ano-hana-episode-1/ has

```
<embed src="http://www.4shared.com/embed/571660264/396a46be"></embed>
```

, though the link to the video seems to be
"http://dc436.4shared.com/img/571660264/396a46be/dlink__2Fdownload_2FM2b0O5Rr_3Ftsid_3D20120514-093834-29c48ef9/preview.flv"

How does the browser know where to load the video from? How can I write code that converts the embed link to a direct link?

UPDATE:
Thanks for the quick answer, Quentin.
However, I don't seem to receive a 'Location' header when connecting to "http://www.4shared.com/embed/571660264/396a46be".

```
import urllib2
r=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.4shared.com/embed/571660264/396a46be')
```

gives me the following headers:
'content-length', 'via', 'x-cache', 'accept-ranges', 'server', 'x-cache-lookup', 'last-modified', 'connection', 'etag', 'date', 'content-type', 'x-jsl'

```
from urllib2 import Request
r=Request('http://www.4shared.com/embed/571660264/396a46be')
```

gives me no headers at all.

Comment: You need to show some more code to demonstrate how you make the request. Most HTTP libraries will, by default, follow redirects automatically so won't tell you about the direct.

Comment: @Quentin: So it's a python issue after all? Fine, I'll update the tags and the question.

Answer (score 1):

The server issues a [302 HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) and [a Location header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30).

```
$ curl -I http://www.4shared.com/embed/571660264/396a46be
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

(snip cookies)

Location: http://static.4shared.com/flash/player/5.6/player.swf?file=http://dc436.4shared.com/img/M2b0O5Rr/gg_Ano_Hi_Mita_Hana_no_Namae_o.flv&provider=image&image=http://dc436.4shared.com/img/M2b0O5Rr/gg_Ano_Hi_Mita_Hana_no_Namae_o.flv&displayclick=link&link=http://www.4shared.com/video/M2b0O5Rr/gg_Ano_Hi_Mita_Hana_no_Namae_o.html&controlbar=none
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 14 May 2012 10:01:59 GMT
```

---

See [How do I prevent Python's urllib(2) from following a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554446/how-do-i-prevent-pythons-urllib2-from-following-a-redirect) if you want to get information about the redirect response instead of following the redirect automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot! No unnecessary information/text there!
However, I'm not receiving a 'Location' header. I'm updating the question.

Comment: Actually, I guess I'm stupid for not having noticed until now, but there's no link to any video file. 'Location' links to the 4shared player, two video thumbnails and the 4shared website.