# How to detect if a request has been redirected and if so dokument it in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, redirect, python-requests

i'm trying to catch if a request that i send to many websites, has been redirected or not. first let me give you some example Data.

```
redirected_urls = [
    "http://www.tagesschau.de/inland/vw-schalte-hapke-101.html",
    "http://de.reuters.com/article/deutschland-volkswagen-idDEKCN10V0H3"
]

healthy_urls = [
    "http://www.focus.de/finanzen/news/wirtschaftsticker/machtkampf-zwischen-vw-und-zulieferern-stoppt-autoproduktion_id_5842241.html",
    "https://www.bild.de/news/aktuelles/news/vw-kuendigt-harte-gangart-gegen-lieferstopp-47400500.bild.html"
]


redirected_df = pd.DataFrame({'URL': redirected_urls})
healthy_df = pd.DataFrame({'URL': healthy_urls})
```

so in redirected_df are the links that actually get redirected, however the other dataframe is not redirected. As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482777/how-to-detect-when-a-site-check-redirects-to-another-page-using-the-requests-mod) i tried to set `allow_redirects=False` then realized all the links that i'm using get redirected somehow, although i get to see the actual news article. So the response code for all is 200, meaning successful connection. Then i checked `response.history` for almost all of the link i get `[<Response [301]>]` . Using `BeautifulSoup(response._content).find('link', {'rel': 'canonical'})` they all have values.

then i would like to save this info in my dataframe like this `_df.at[k,'Is_Redirected']= 1 if response.history else 0`. For all links as mentioned above i get 1 (True).

The code that i'm using:

```
def send_two_requests(_url):
        try:
            headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36"}
            response = requests.get(_url,headers=headers,allow_redirects=True, timeout=10)
            return response
        except:
            return func_timeout.func_timeout(timeout=5, func=send_request, args=[_url])   


for k,link in enumerate(_df['url']):      
 response =  send_two_requests(_df.at[k,'url']) 
                if  response is not None:
                    _df.at[k,'Is_Redirected']= 1 if response.history else 0
```

is there  anyway i can distinguish the actual links that work, and the ones that get redirected?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just wanted to see if the Links get redirected or not. I noticed that many URLs that i have change in a minor way, for example most of them are using `http` while the actual website is in `Https` therefor it would flag as redirected, however it's actually not redirected and i'm seeing the same page. So i tried to check the differences between the Response URL and the URL that i have with `difflib` Library.  If the Links are 99% similar then i don't consider this a redirected URL.

```
if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, response.url, _df.at[k,'URL']).ratio()>=0.99:
                            _df.at[k,'is_redirected']=0
                        else:
                            _df.at[k,'is_redirected']=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can check if the page was redirected by observing the `response.history` (if it's non-empty, you're redirected):

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

all_urls = [
    "http://www.tagesschau.de/inland/vw-schalte-hapke-101.html",
    "http://de.reuters.com/article/deutschland-volkswagen-idDEKCN10V0H3",
    "http://www.focus.de/finanzen/news/wirtschaftsticker/machtkampf-zwischen-vw-und-zulieferern-stoppt-autoproduktion_id_5842241.html",
    "https://www.bild.de/news/aktuelles/news/vw-kuendigt-harte-gangart-gegen-lieferstopp-47400500.bild.html",
]

all_data = []
for url in all_urls:
    resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    all_data.append(
        {"url": url, "final_url": resp.url, "is_redirected": len(resp.history) > 0}
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                                                                url                                                                                                                          final_url  is_redirected
0                                                                         http://www.tagesschau.de/inland/vw-schalte-hapke-101.html                                                                                                   https://www.tagesschau.de/inland           True
1                                                                http://de.reuters.com/article/deutschland-volkswagen-idDEKCN10V0H3                                                                                        https://www.reuters.com?edition-redirect=de           True
2  http://www.focus.de/finanzen/news/wirtschaftsticker/machtkampf-zwischen-vw-und-zulieferern-stoppt-autoproduktion_id_5842241.html  https://www.focus.de/finanzen/news/wirtschaftsticker/machtkampf-zwischen-vw-und-zulieferern-stoppt-autoproduktion_id_5842241.html           True
3                            https://www.bild.de/news/aktuelles/news/vw-kuendigt-harte-gangart-gegen-lieferstopp-47400500.bild.html                             https://www.bild.de/news/aktuelles/news/vw-kuendigt-harte-gangart-gegen-lieferstopp-47400500.bild.html          False
```