# Capture all live HTTP header data

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

I'm not seeing that this is possible using Requests module, but maybe I'm missing something...

I need to be able to capture all the live HTTP header data that, for example, a Firefox plugin such as the creatively named [Live HTTP Headers plugin](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/)

Is there a method for capturing header data so that I can collect the following (or as close to the following as possible)?:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb0096f08a3848e6a355f&amp;redirect_uri=https://pythondev.geometryfletch.com/instagramredirect.html&amp;response_type=code&amp;hl=hu

GET /oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb0096f08a3848e6a355f&amp;redirect_uri=https://pythondev.geometryfletch.com/instagramredirect.html&amp;response_type=code&amp;hl=hu HTTP/1.1
Host: instagram.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: csrftoken=4d9696d270a1d2d7b4d1b5; mid=U8lMswAEAAGyEMGTjENK; __utma=227057989.1190820776.1417498356.1417498356.1417498356.1; sessionid=IGSCb5786690876faa5d2505e1d8b3782691614164cb344c52ec2a6714cb5e1cd884%3Akds8RALygAnGbeQMAiLU%3A%7B%22_token_ver%22%3A1%2C%22_auth_user_id%22%3A324232C%22_token%22%3A9437%3A1lhXdDvRNvbT4MS1J5QpeBmG%3Ac0ccc4aebd1d88175db75c9ce360ad595c55946577bcb9ebc%22%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1436481638.349811%2C%22_platform%22%3A4%7D; ds_user_id=324239437
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Language: hu
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 09 Jul 2015 22:46:21 GMT
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Location: https://pythondev.devtesting.com/instagramredirect.html?code=2c49fd7803384c6c5a89cee
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=4d9696dac6b0d5b8591b5; expires=Thu, 07-Jul-2016 22:46:21 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

All I really need out of this is the URL string value for `Location` that look likes this:

```
Location: https://pythondev.devtesting.com/instagramredirect.html?code=2c49fd7803384c6c5a89cee
```

After searching around for possible solutions, I've been trying variations on the following (client_id and redirect altered for this post):

```
OAuthURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb00962b4601317355f&redirect_uri=https://pythondev.instadev.com/instagramredirect.html&response_type=code"
r = requests.get(OAuthURL, stream=True)
print r.raw.data
```

But obviously, I get this garbled stuff:

```
ôrË¼ÖtÉxlÏß5g·Ì{þµ¼æ®6×MÆ¦¶Ök:µ#î^Bm,\ûf+ÈÕúµçoO´Úö3ut×]Ta¡*_@[BsÊqgÅëêw×ûQÁç)óf-ÕD[³Û®3×*ï¥Ôï`æ:$nÑÞZ£ô)©ª[}«ØBA"¿²å¿*ÜÞ1BuÄ¹!DGwËUhµ?:PnmwbâÿK¯ÈIÅ¡#2R¸@¼'ø>"dPtOÈm"W fÞ xöñ­¯vmG cÆÔ>÷Î¿aâykãyk¤=²"ù*A¦=ýz=²3&¤ö©½õ CËIMÛÓ¯6Î(íirG*«
```

Would [Sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) work for this? Or is there another module out there I could use that would allow me to collect header the same way a web browser HTTP header plugin would?

Answer (score 1):

`requests` returns the headers for you. You can use `dict`-style access to get them.

If you want `request.get` to return the redirect response rather than automatically following it, specify `allow_redirects=False`.

```
#UNTESTED
OAuthURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb00962b4601317355f&redirect_uri=https://pythondev.instadev.com/instagramredirect.html&response_type=code"
r = requests.get(OAuthURL, stream=True, allow_redirects=False)
print r.headers.keys()
print r.headers['location']
```

Alternatively, specify `allow_redirects=True` (the default value), and examine `r.history`:

```
#UNTESTED
OAuthURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb00962b4601317355f&redirect_uri=https://pythondev.instadev.com/instagramredirect.html&response_type=code"
r = requests.get(OAuthURL, stream=True, allow_redirects=True)
print [resp.headers['location'] for resp in r.history]
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but still getting this garbled response:  `ô#Uÿå\msÚHþî_¡h×"d±1R¹Ä©JÕímjÔÞU£©ÆfÍú¿_ÏHáI|ë|UÒ¼t·éyºehÆO^ÿöêÃÞ9±JéÞøç}¢(çísòyê×X÷: aÌuH9q÷.$õ(oÃâíÄa\y _, ô(sÜ©3~ò`

Comment: Then you aren't printing `r.headers.keys()`. It looks like you are still printing r.raw.data.

Comment: Ah, ok, fixed that, thanks. Getting this error now:     `print r.headers['location']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'location'`

Comment: That means that the server didn't return a location header. You can examine the list of keys to see which headers it *did* return.

Comment: Ok, so even if an HTTP header plugin on a browser displays the redirect URL I'm looking for as the value for `location` in the response, Requests isn't finding it as that?

Comment: Consider specifying `allow_redirects=False` or examining `r.history`. See my recent edit.

Comment: Thanks for the added options here, appreciate it. No matter what I try, I just keep getting the `OAuthURL` for `location` instead of what I'm seeing for location in the browser HTTP header plugin (which actually contains the OAuth access code I need).