# Python - Don't follow redirect on one URL only

Tags: python, redirect, urllib2

I'm wondering how you can prevent urllib2 from following a redirect request on my chosen url. I found this snippet of code while browsing but it seems it works globally and I only want it to disable redirect on a certain url:

```
import urllib2
class RedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        result = urllib2.HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, headers, fp)
        result.status = code
        return result
    http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302

opener = urllib2.build_opener(RedirectHandler())
webpage = opener.open('http://www.website.com').geturl()
print webpage
```

I also should mention that I am requesting a url using urllib.urlopen('site.com') and I want the first redirect to be allowed to happen for example say site.com redirects to site.com/redirect but then it tries to redirect again from site.com/redirect to site.com/secondredirect I would like the script to recognise "secondredirect" within the url and stop that request from happening. I hope I explained this all and well and hope to see some replies as I have spent hours upon hours trying to figure this out :headache:

Comment: What do you mean by `stop the request from happening`?

Comment: EDIT: Misread. I mean just totally not follow the redirect on the chosen url.

Comment: Hi, where did your answer go? I was just trying it out to see if it worked?

Comment: Try it, i deleted it because i haven't sure it will work or not, and i have to leave my computer for a second.

Comment: I think right now, i cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a way to disable redirect-following on a per-request basis with urllib2. You have the option of using [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) which is normally a low-level module used by modules like urllib2.

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.bogosoft.com")
>>> conn.request("GET", "")
>>> r1 = conn.getresponse()
>>> print r1.status, r1.reason
301 Moved Permanently
>>> print r1.getheader('Location')
http://www.bogosoft.com/new/location
```

Another option is using the [Python Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, which gives you more fine-grained control over [how to handle redirects](https://3.python-requests.org/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history). Requests is the better choice here in my opinion, if you have the option of using another library.

Comment: Well I already made a full program using urllib2 :/, so I'm guessing I'll have to re-write it using httplib/python requests library? Also given your example above say that http://www.bogosoft.com/new/location decides to redirect again to lets say http://www.bogosoft.com/new/location2, would we be able to detect that using either of these two modules?

Comment: httplib does not follow redirects, so by definition, you can detect each riderect by checking the status code. When you use `allow_redirects=False` with the requests library, it will behave like httplib, so you will be able to detect redirects with that as well by checking the status code.

Comment: Hmm so these do not solve my problem then because I am trying to visit a site url and block the second redirect of that url not the first :(

Comment: You can use the method here http://www.zacwitte.com/resolving-http-redirects-in-python and break the recursion on the second redirect. I don't see any library or method which follows "n redirects" and no more. They either follow redirects, or they don't. You will have to do this by counting the redirects yourself.

Comment: Thanks, seems like it would work but what's the point in having exception there? Wouldn't it just end the script if too many redirects occur? (More than the specified amount which is 10 by default without my edit.)

Answer (score 6):

```
import urllib.request

class RedirectFilter(urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def redirect_request(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs, newurl):
        if newurl.endswith('.jpg'):
            return None # do not redirect, HTTPError will be raised
        return urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler.redirect_request(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs, newurl)

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(RedirectFilter)

opener.open('http://example.com/')
```

This is for Python 3. For Python 2 replace `urllib.request` with `urllib2`.