# To print http status code in Python 3 (urllib)

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to get http status codes including 3XX, but from my code I'm not able to print it.

Here is the code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

urls = ['http://hotdot.pro/en/404/', 'http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yandex.ru', 'http://www.python.org', 'http://www.voidspace.org.uk']
fh = open("example.txt", "a")
def getUrl(urls):
   for url in urls:
        try:
           with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
                requrl = url
                the_page = response.code
                fh.write("%d, %s\n" % (int(the_page), str(requrl)))
        except (urllib.error.HTTPError, urllib.error.URLError)  as e:
            requrl = url
            print (e.code)
            fh.write("%d, %s\n" % (int(e.code), str(requrl)))
getUrl(urls)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: is your real question: how to disable redirects? (so that `urlopen()` won't follow any 30x redirects automatically?)

Comment: Yes, I do not want the url to be redirected. Just to print the response codes along with response time.

Comment: see [Is there an easy way to request a URL in python and NOT follow redirects?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/110498/4279)

Answer (score 7):

Not all errors of class `URLError` will have a `code`, some will only have a `reason`.

Besides, *catching* `URLError` and `HTTPError` in the same `except` block is not a good idea (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/howto/urllib2.html#number-1)):

```
def getUrl(urls):
   for url in urls:
        try:
           with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
                log(fh, response.code, url)
        except urllib.error.HTTPError  as e:
            log(fh, e.code, url)
        except urllib.error.URLError as e:
            if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
                log(fh, e.reason, url)
            elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
                log(fh, e.code, url)

 def log(fh, item, url):
     print(item)
     fh.write("%s, %s\n" % (item, url))
```

Answer (score 5):

Instantiate the following in your code.

```
   try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        code = response.getcode()
        print(code)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error:  {url} : {str(e)}')
```

Answer (score 4):

Try python's requests package. ([docs here](https://pypi.org/project/requests/))

Bit more straightforward and very easy to print http status codes.

```
import requests

URL = 'http://yourURL:8080'
query = {'your': 'dictionary to send'}

response = requests.post(URL, data=query)

return response.status_code
```

Comment: is the requests from > [here](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.7.0/user/install/) using `pip install requests`? IF so you should have mentioned that in your answer.