# How do I prevent a python script from being redirected from a specific web page?

Tags: python, http, redirect

For example, I tried getting Python to read the following filtered page

`http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards?filter-attack-val=1&filter-attack-op=1&display=1`

but Python only gets the unfiltered page `http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards` instead.

Comment: What library are you using for this? `requests`? You should update your post to include a minimal working example of your code to show what you have been doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to request a URL in python and NOT follow redirects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110498/is-there-an-easy-way-to-request-a-url-in-python-and-not-follow-redirects)

Comment: @Anthon I use the standard urllib2 way of fetching urls. I'll update the post later when i have access to my pc. I should note that it used to work before, but now it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library `urllib2` normally follows redirects. If retrieving this URL used to work without being redirected, then the site has changed.

Although you can prevent following the redirect within `urllib2` (by providing an alternative HTTP handler), I recommend using [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests), where you can do:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards?filter-attack-val=1'
                 '&filter-attack-op=1&display=1', allow_redirects=False)
print(r)
```

giving you:

```
<Response [302]>
```

Comment: Very straightforward solution. Thanks!