# Follow redirect using http.client

Tags: python, python-3.x, redirect, http.client

Is there a way to automatically follow redirects using the `http.client` module:

```
def grab_url(host, path = '/'):
  class Data: pass
  result = Data()
  try:
    con = http.client.HTTPConnection(host)
    con.request('GET', path)
    response = con.getresponse()
    if response.status == 200:
      result.content = response.read().decode('utf-8')
      result.headers = response.getheaders()
  catch Exception as e:
    print(e)
  return result
```

The above works as long as the request returns a http response of `200`, but I don't know how to handle redirects like `301`?

Using `pyCurl` I would simply set the `FOLLOWLOCATION` to `True`:

```
def grab_url(host, path = '/'):
  buffer = BytesIO()
  c = pyCurl.Curl()
  c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
  c.setopt(c.URL, host + path)
  c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
  c.perform()
  status = c.getinfo(c.RESPONSE_CODE)
  if status == 200:
    return buffer.getvalue().decode('iso-8859-1')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url?answertab=votes#tab-top ? i will suggest you to use requests instead if you can

Comment: @toheedNiaz yes I know I could use curl or requests but is this not possible using the http.client module?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/110547/2699643 here is something that explains what you want