# How to sys.exit when a webpage re-directs using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

So my idea was to basically make something simple when a page re-directs it should just quit the script. Meaning:

Legit page: https://www.stackoverflow.com
Redirected: https://www.stackoverflow.com/Helloworld

Right now I am just using

```
import requests

try:
    r = requests.get('https://www.stackoverflow.com')
    print r.status_code

except:
    sys.exit()
```

what I want to do is that whenever it the `requests.get` gets re-directed. It should hit the exception where I later can use `sys.exit()` Or it should just `sys.exit()` overall if it redirects.

Comment: Could you disable redirect following and check whether the first status code is 3xx?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to request a URL in python and NOT follow redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110498/is-there-an-easy-way-to-request-a-url-in-python-and-not-follow-redirects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All redirects will have a status code like 3xx (which you can see in [the HTTP standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)). You can check the status code and use a regex to match it to that pattern. If it matches that pattern, then exit.

```
import re
import sys
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.stackoverflow.com')
if re.search(r'^3', str(r.status_code)):
    sys.exit()
```

[**EDIT**]: Left out the `str` around `r.status_code` because it's an integer.

Comment: Ohh! I didn't knew it changes the status code. In that case I will just use this one as answer! Thanks!

Comment: Im getting an issue thought now when I see it!
`expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere because the status code isn't a string, and it also *won't* be 3xx by default. Not sure why you've accepted this.

Comment: Well what you just needed to do is `str(r.status_code)` instead