# Login to this site with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I try to automate the login to this site via requests, by working with session for the first time.

https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/login

I would like to for example get the contents of this page, when a user is logged in.

https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/dashboard/mijn-gegevens?

I created a login on the site, for this purpose only:

Login: hoegje+pepepepe@gmail.com
Password: PepePepe

But when I try to do the POST to the login page, I get a 200  OK response, while on the site with devtools I get a 302 redirect and it redirects me to the first page of the site.

```
        s = requests.session()
        #Try to accept cookies
        cookieData = {'cookies_functional': 'true', 'cookies_analytics': 'true', 'cookies_social': 'false',
                      'cookies_media': 'false', 'cookies_accepted': 'true'}
        expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=52)  # expires in 1 year
        for aCookieKey, aCookieValue in cookieData.items():
            acceptCookiesCookie = requests.cookies.create_cookie(aCookieKey, aCookieValue, domain='www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be', path='/', expires=expires.timestamp())
            s.cookies.set_cookie(acceptCookiesCookie)
            acceptCookiesCookie = requests.cookies.create_cookie(aCookieKey, aCookieValue, path='www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/', expires=expires.timestamp())
            s.cookies.set_cookie(acceptCookiesCookie)
        # Response sets cookie: INGRESSCOOKIE = 1695315839.247.1714.732149|60903facce0df50e07e804a3a5c147b8
        firstResponse = s.get("https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/login", headers={
            "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
            "referer": "https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/", "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.31"})
        print('=' * 50)
        print(s.cookies)
        print(firstResponse.cookies)
        print('=' * 50)

        print(s.cookies)
        submitCookies = s.cookies
        #{originalJsessionId}
        lfrSessionStateTs = str(int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000))
        originalJsessionId = s.cookies.get('JSESSIONID')
        originalIngressCookie = s.cookies.get('INGRESSCOOKIE')
        print(f"originalJsessionId {originalJsessionId}")
        print(f'f1 {firstResponse}')
        print(f'f2 {firstResponse.cookies}')
        print(f'f3 {firstResponse.headers}')
        print(f'f4 {firstResponse.request}')
        print(f'f5 {firstResponse.text.find("Liferay.authToken")}')
        i1 = firstResponse.text.find("Liferay.authToken")
        i2 = firstResponse.text.find(";", i1)
        Liferay_authToken = firstResponse.text[i1:i2]
        print(Liferay_authToken)
        i1 = Liferay_authToken.find("'") + 1
        i2 = Liferay_authToken.rfind("'")
        pAuthRandom = Liferay_authToken[i1:i2]
        secondResponse = s.get("https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/login", headers={
            "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
            "cache-control": "max-age=0",
            "cookie": f"INGRESSCOOKIE={originalIngressCookie}; JSESSIONID={originalJsessionId}; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=nl_NL; LFR_SESSION_STATE_20101={lfrSessionStateTs}; cookies_functional=true; cookies_analytics=true; cookies_social=true; cookies_media=true; cookies_accepted=true",
            "referer": "https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/login", "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.31"},
              cookies=submitCookies)
        print(f's1 {secondResponse}')
        print(f's2 {secondResponse.cookies}')
        print(f's3 {secondResponse.headers}')
        print(f's4 {secondResponse.request}')
        print(f's5 {secondResponse.request}')

        # Redirects to: https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/dashboard/nieuws-en-evenementen
        # TODO add content-length to headers: 'content-length': str(contentLength),
        # import string
        # characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        # pAuthRandom = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(8))
        print(f"pAuthRandom {pAuthRandom}")
        dataToSubmit = {
                     "_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_formDate": f"{lfrSessionStateTs}",
                     "_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_saveLastPath": "false",
                    "_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_redirect": "",
                    "_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_doActionAfterLogin": "false",
                     "_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_portletPath": "%2Flogin",
                     "_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_login": "hoegje%2Bpepepepe%40gmail.com",
                     "_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_password": "PepePepe",
                     "p_auth": pAuthRandom
                        }
        dataStringToSubmit = ''
        for aKey, aValue in dataToSubmit.items():
            dataStringToSubmit += f'{aKey}={aValue}&'
        dataStringToSubmit = dataStringToSubmit[:-1]
        contentLength = len(str(dataStringToSubmit))   # 2 brackets, 4 for None
        postReply = s.post("https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/login",
               params={"p_p_id": "com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet", "p_p_lifecycle": "0", "p_p_state": "normal",
                       "p_p_mode": "view",
                       "_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_javax.portlet.action": "%2Flogin%2Flogin",
                       "_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_mvcRenderCommandName": "%2Flogin%2Flogin"},
               data=dataStringToSubmit,
               headers={
                "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
                "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
                "cache-control": "max-age=0", 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                "cookie": f"INGRESSCOOKIE={originalIngressCookie}; JSESSIONID={originalJsessionId}; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=nl_NL; cookies_functional=true; cookies_analytics=true; cookies_social=true; cookies_media=true; cookies_accepted=true; LFR_SESSION_STATE_20101={lfrSessionStateTs}",
                "origin": "https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be", 'content-length': str(contentLength),
                "referer": "https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/login", "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
                "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.31",
                           'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0','sec-ch-ua-platform': "Windows", 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
                   'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin', 'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1', 'sec-gpc': '1', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
                   'Connection': 'keep-alive'
                },
               cookies=s.cookies)
        print(f'p1 {postReply}')
        print(f'p2 {postReply.cookies}')
        print(f'p3 {postReply.headers}')
        print(f'p4 {postReply.request}')
        print(f'p5 {postReply.request}')
        # Response sets cookie: JSESSIONID = DECCD37CCA427785F666166AB6CB085E
        finalResponse = s.get("https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/dashboard/nieuws-en-evenementen", headers={
            "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
            "cache-control": "max-age=0",
            "cookie": f"INGRESSCOOKIE={originalIngressCookie}; JSESSIONID={originalJsessionId}; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=nl_NL; cookies_functional=true; cookies_analytics=true; cookies_social=true; cookies_media=true; cookies_accepted=true; LFR_SESSION_STATE_20101={lfrSessionStateTs}",
            "referer": "https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/login", "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.31"},
              cookies=s.cookies)
        print(finalResponse)
        print(finalResponse.headers)
        print(finalResponse.text.find('Pepe'))
        print(postReply.text)
```

Edit: added unredacted code, since the shorter version was not enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Comparing the requests made in an interactive browser session and those made by your code, what is the difference?

Comment: I can't find any difference at all. Only the reply from the POST is 302 in the browser, and regular 200 in my script. No idea about the error, as I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Actually shortened the code. Actual code is now in the edited question. posting it in a comment was too long.

Comment: Try using selenium

Comment: Would love to do it with just requests. Pretty sure it is possible, since when I disable javascript in my browser, and try to login, it also accepts it. It shows a slightly different page, with only the left side (frame?), but at least it logs it in and I can still browse from page to page, with logged in user.

Comment: You note that the immediate response is a 302 redirect, but you didn't see this behavior with requests. This could be because requests followed the redirect for you. You can avoid this with allow_redirects=False https://stackoverflow.com/a/14678220/1766544 This would make it possible for you to figure out specific issues at each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to login to page using only requests you need to recreate behaviour of logging that is in desired page.

I usually recommend looking into networking tab to see what requests are send, also a lot of times in forms there are hidden fields that we need to send as well.

Logging with requests:

```py
from requests import Session
from lxml import etree

my_pass = "PepePepe"
my_login = "hoegje+pepepepe@gmail.com"

login_page_url = "https://www.tennisenpadelvlaanderen.be/dashboard/mijn-gegevens"

session = Session()

# Get logging page first (also sometimes sets correct cookies that we want)
login_page_response = session.get(login_page_url)
# create etree from loging page's html
root = etree.HTML(login_page_response.text)

# Find logging form element
form_element = root.xpath(".//div[@class='login-container']/form")[0]
# get url that we need to use in post request
post_login_url = form_element.xpath('./@action')[0]

# get hidden inputs names
hidden_elements_names = form_element.xpath('.//input[@type="hidden"]/@name')
# get hidden inputs values
hidden_elements_values = form_element.xpath('.//input[@type="hidden"]/@value')

data_dict = dict(zip(hidden_elements_names, hidden_elements_values))

# update data that we gonna send with our credentials
data_dict["_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_login"] = my_login
data_dict["_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_password"] = my_pass

# login to site
login_response = session.post(post_login_url, data=data_dict)
# here login_response have status code 200
# if you want for login_response to have status code 302 like in dev tools, 
# but then your request won't be redirected to dashboard page automatically
# login_response = session.post(post_login_url, data=data_dict, allow_redirects=False)

print(login_response.text.find('Pepe'))
# >>> 59730 (or -1 if allow_redirects=False)
```